# How to create two different sessions depending on user privilege in MySQL and PHP

Tags: php, mysql, sql, session, privileges

I want to have two different sessions - an Admin and normal user session, depending on what their privilege is set to. I have the following tables:

```
---- LOGIN ----

Login ID | Username  | Password          | StaffID (FK) 
-------------------------------------------------------
1        | bob.jones | *hashed password* | 1

---- ROLES ---- 

RoleID | Role   | Privilege
---------------------------
1      | Worker | Normal 
2      | CEO    | Admin

---- JOBS ----

JobID | StaffID | PlaceID | RoleID
---------------------------------- 
1     | 1       | 1       | 1 
2     | 2       | 1       | 2
```

I have the following snippet from my login process. This is where privilege is set to Enum.

```php
...
else if ($pwdCheck == True){  
  session_start();
  $query = mysqli_query($conn, 'SELECT staff.StaffID, role.Privilege FROM
    jobs
    INNER JOIN staff ON staff.StaffID = jobs.StaffID
    INNER JOIN role ON role.RoleID = jobs.RoleID
    WHERE login.Username = ?????????');

  $gettier = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query);

  if((int)$gettier["Privilege"] === 0){
    $_SESSION['userID'] = $row['LoginID'];
    header("Location: staffindex.php?login=USERsuccess");
  }
  elseif((int)$gettier["Privilege"] === 1){
    $_SESSION['AdminID'] = $row['LoginID'];
    header("Location: staffindex.php?login=ADMINsuccess");
  }

  exit();
}
```

Any help is appreciated,
Thanks

Comment: you need to tell us what the problem is with the above code. Privilege is Normal or Admin, your checking if it is 0 or 1

Comment: Privilege is Admin, where Normal == 0 and and Admin == 1. When I try to run this snippet ALL users redirect as USERsuccess.

Comment: `$gettier["Privilege"]` will be Normal or Admin not 1\0, if you want 1\0 you need to  use `RoleID`

Comment: As @tim says, `$gettier["Privilege"]` will be `Normal` or `Admin` so `(int)$gettier["Privilege"]` will **always** be 0. You need to compare `$gettier["Privilege"] === 'Normal'` instead.

Comment: or he can replace `role.Privilege` with  `role.RoleID` in the query and check  `$gettier["RoleID"]` instead for 1\0, potato\potato

Comment: I think that the main error I have has to do with the query:   $query = mysqli_query($conn, 'SELECT staff.StaffID, role.Privilege FROM
jobs
INNER JOIN staff ON staff.StaffID = jobs.StaffID
INNER JOIN role ON role.RoleID = jobs.RoleID'); In reality, my Admins ALSO have user roles, so I think I need to have a group by statement using an aggregate string function?

Answer (score 0):

As pointed out in your comment, you are executing a query that may return several rows for a person having both admin and normal role, one for each job/role the user has but you are only querying one row from the result (and you also miss to check if the query returns at least one row; in case the user does not exist, this will create an error as you perform `mysqli_fetch_assoc($query)` on an empty query result).

I would also recommend to use the role names instead of any IDs as IDs may change whereas the role name should remain the same.

**Code:**

```
  $isAdmin= FALSE;
  $isUser= FALSE;

  $query = mysqli_query($conn, 'SELECT staff.StaffID, role.Privilege FROM
    jobs
    INNER JOIN staff ON staff.StaffID = jobs.StaffID
    INNER JOIN role ON role.RoleID = jobs.RoleID
    WHERE login.Username = ?????????');


  while ($gettier = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query)) {
      if($gettier["Privilege"] === "Normal"){
        $_SESSION['userID'] = $row['LoginID'];
        $isUser= TRUE;
      }
      elseif($gettier["Privilege"] === "Admin"){
        $_SESSION['AdminID'] = $row['LoginID'];
        $isAdmin= TRUE;
      }
  }

  // redirect the user based on the $isAdmin/$isUser flag
  if ($isAdmin) {
    header("Location: staffindex.php?login=ADMINsuccess");
  } elseif ($isUser) {
    header("Location: staffindex.php?login=USERsuccess");
  } else {
    // User not found.
  }
```